# Exchange 2003, put message on hold for one user

Tags: exchange, zimbra, imapsync

I'm migrating from Exchange 2003 to Zimbra 8.6 using imapsync
I need to make sure that during the imapsync process no email are delivered to the Exchange account (because it's possible to lost them)

I can put them on hold if coming from the Internet using the antispam appliance, but how can I do the same within the same domain?

Internet -> antispam -> exchange == OK (antispam put the mail on queue and I can release it later)

exchange -> exchange == ??

Answer (score 0):

No message will be lost during the migration. If a new message arrive then it will be synced by imapsync on the next run. Imapsync allows multiple syncs between the same accounts, without making duplicates.

Comment: Hi Gilles, thank you for your answer but I am talking about the last imapsync, just before removing the mailbox on Exchange, because is going to be a semi-transparent migration I can't deny access to everyone but just to one account at once

Comment: I don't fully understand your picture. You can deny access by changing the password.